# Jetpack Composable gets disposed when SurfaceView is playing video and navigates back to previous screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, surfaceview

I am adding a surfaceView wrapped inside AndroidView to play some video, here is the snippet of it -

```
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_player, FrameLayout(context), false)

            val aspectRatioFrameLayout = view.findViewById<AspectRatioFrameLayout>(R.id.aspect_ratio_frame_layout)
            aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(videoAspectRatioValue)

            val surfaceView = view.findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surface_view)
            surfaceView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
                override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {
                    attachSurface(view as SurfaceView)
                }

                override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
                    detachSurface(view as SurfaceView)
                }
            })

            return@AndroidView view
        }
    )
```

and seeing random closing/disposing of the composable and navigating back to its previous screen when the video is playing and here is the logs that I am getting right now when it happens. the detach is just from the surface view detach callback set right now and then afterwards the composable is disposed. how can I fix this? is this an internal bug with surface view and composable?

```
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=1
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=2
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=3
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=4
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=5
 15:08:31.242 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=6
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=0
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=1
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=2
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=3
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=4
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=5
 15:08:31.253 21064-21064 SurfaceSyncer                            E  Failed to find sync for id=6
 15:08:31.626 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 1774/1780 (recycle/alloc) - 6/1779 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:31.955 21064-21631 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(138) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:33.566 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 1766/1771 (recycle/alloc) - 5/1770 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:33.966 21064-21642 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(412) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:35.974 21064-21646 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(103) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:36.677 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 2074/2080 (recycle/alloc) - 6/2079 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:37.982 21064-21651 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(224) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:38.931 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 2016/2021 (recycle/alloc) - 5/2020 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:39.994 21064-21661 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(135) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:41.729 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 2380/2386 (recycle/alloc) - 6/2385 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:42.001 21064-21666 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(287) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:44.010 21064-21670 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(134) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:44.441 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 2275/2280 (recycle/alloc) - 5/2279 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:46.019 21064-21680 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(241) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:46.803 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 2683/2689 (recycle/alloc) - 6/2689 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:48.027 21064-21682 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(274) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:49.972 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 2533/2538 (recycle/alloc) - 5/2537 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:50.038 21064-21686 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(284) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:51.889 21064-21469 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 2989/2995 (recycle/alloc) - 6/2994 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:52.044 21064-21723 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(175) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:54.055 21064-21801 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(124) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:55.424 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 2792/2797 (recycle/alloc) - 5/2797 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:56.067 21064-21805 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(152) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:08:56.957 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 3292/3298 (recycle/alloc) - 6/3298 (fetch/transfer)
 15:08:58.079 21064-21815 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(138) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:00.090 21064-21820 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(178) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:00.930 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 3048/3053 (recycle/alloc) - 5/3052 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:02.036 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 3596/3602 (recycle/alloc) - 6/3602 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:02.098 21064-21824 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(99) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:04.106 21064-21831 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(105) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:06.113 21064-21839 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(99) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:06.371 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 3303/3308 (recycle/alloc) - 5/3307 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:07.098 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 3900/3906 (recycle/alloc) - 6/3906 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:08.124 21064-21844 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(133) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:10.133 21064-21848 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(373) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:11.400 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 3538/3543 (recycle/alloc) - 5/3542 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:12.146 21064-21988 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(206) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:12.173 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 4204/4210 (recycle/alloc) - 6/4209 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:14.153 21064-21995 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(124) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:14.341 21064-21073 bo.mobile.debug                          I  Compiler allocated 4100KB to compile java.util.List androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathNodeKt.toPathNodes(char, float[])
 15:09:16.162 21064-22002 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(250) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:16.807 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 3792/3797 (recycle/alloc) - 5/3796 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:17.223 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 4507/4513 (recycle/alloc) - 6/4512 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:18.172 21064-22012 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(341) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:20.184 21064-22016 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(312) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:22.193 21064-22021 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(271) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:22.206 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 4046/4051 (recycle/alloc) - 5/4050 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:22.284 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 4810/4816 (recycle/alloc) - 6/4815 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:24.202 21064-22036 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(172) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:26.214 21064-22040 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(206) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:27.333 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 5113/5119 (recycle/alloc) - 6/5119 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:27.647 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 4301/4306 (recycle/alloc) - 5/4305 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:28.223 21064-22044 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(297) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:30.237 21064-22055 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(138) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:32.246 21064-22059 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(407) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:32.393 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 5416/5422 (recycle/alloc) - 6/5422 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:33.085 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 4556/4561 (recycle/alloc) - 5/4560 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:34.257 21064-22063 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(133) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:36.269 21064-22073 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(299) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:36.943 21064-21473 PipelineWatcher                          D  onInputBufferReleased: frameIndex not found (5690); ignored
 15:09:37.495 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 5722/5728 (recycle/alloc) - 6/5728 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:38.279 21064-22077 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(134) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:38.524 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 4811/4816 (recycle/alloc) - 5/4815 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:40.291 21064-22081 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(150) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:42.299 21064-22118 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(150) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:42.553 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 6025/6031 (recycle/alloc) - 6/6030 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:43.562 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 5046/5051 (recycle/alloc) - 5/5050 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:44.313 21064-22175 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(178) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:46.324 21064-22196 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(185) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:47.598 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 6328/6334 (recycle/alloc) - 6/6334 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:48.336 21064-22208 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(360) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:49.046 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 5304/5309 (recycle/alloc) - 5/5308 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:50.343 21064-22214 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(157) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:52.355 21064-22222 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(219) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:52.655 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 6630/6636 (recycle/alloc) - 6/6636 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:54.368 21064-22232 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(245) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:54.642 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 5565/5570 (recycle/alloc) - 5/5569 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:56.381 21064-22236 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(162) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:57.708 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 6934/6940 (recycle/alloc) - 6/6939 (fetch/transfer)
 15:09:58.391 21064-22240 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(103) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:09:59.683 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 5802/5807 (recycle/alloc) - 5/5806 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:00.399 21064-22250 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(247) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:02.407 21064-22258 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(152) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:02.767 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 7237/7243 (recycle/alloc) - 6/7243 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:04.418 21064-22263 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(249) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:05.204 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 6061/6066 (recycle/alloc) - 5/6065 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:06.428 21064-22274 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(353) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:07.826 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 7540/7546 (recycle/alloc) - 6/7545 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:08.443 21064-22278 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(157) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:10.455 21064-22282 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(148) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:10.763 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 6321/6326 (recycle/alloc) - 5/6325 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:12.466 21064-22292 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(174) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:12.905 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 7845/7851 (recycle/alloc) - 6/7850 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:14.477 21064-22296 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(162) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:16.243 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 6579/6584 (recycle/alloc) - 5/6583 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:16.487 21064-22306 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(150) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:17.969 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 8148/8154 (recycle/alloc) - 6/8153 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:18.497 21064-22318 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(140) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:20.510 21064-22322 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(140) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:21.602 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 6829/6834 (recycle/alloc) - 5/6833 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:22.522 21064-22326 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(382) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:23.049 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 8453/8459 (recycle/alloc) - 6/8459 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:24.530 21064-22342 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(224) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:26.542 21064-22346 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(156) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:26.604 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 7064/7069 (recycle/alloc) - 5/7068 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:28.093 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 8755/8761 (recycle/alloc) - 6/8760 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:28.554 21064-22350 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(209) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:30.562 21064-22360 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(105) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:32.049 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 7318/7323 (recycle/alloc) - 5/7322 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:32.575 21064-22364 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(270) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:33.149 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 9058/9064 (recycle/alloc) - 6/9064 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:34.585 21064-22368 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(185) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:36.592 21064-22378 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(261) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:37.480 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 7573/7578 (recycle/alloc) - 5/7577 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:38.224 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 9362/9368 (recycle/alloc) - 6/9368 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:38.607 21064-22382 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(140) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:40.618 21064-22386 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(103) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:42.632 21064-22398 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(241) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:42.924 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 7829/7834 (recycle/alloc) - 5/7833 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:43.272 21064-21468 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 4(28311552 size) used buffers - 9664/9670 (recycle/alloc) - 6/9670 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:44.641 21064-22402 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(253) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:46.649 21064-22410 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(174) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:48.322 21064-21473 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d40e78 : 5(35389440 size) total buffers - 5(35389440 size) used buffers - 9968/9974 (recycle/alloc) - 6/9973 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:48.367 21064-21479 BufferPoolAccessor2.0                    D  bufferpool2 0xb400007655d4c2d8 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 8084/8089 (recycle/alloc) - 5/8088 (fetch/transfer)
 15:10:48.657 21064-22418 TrafficStats                             D  tagSocket(185) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
 15:10:48.741 21064-21064 bo.mobile.debug                          W  type=1400 audit(0.0:607267): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data//code_cache/startup_agents/3c67707e-agent.so" dev="dm-40" ino=170340 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c77,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c77,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=
 15:10:48.775 21064-21468 SurfaceUtils                             D  connecting to surface 0xb4000076f5ddfff0, reason connectToSurface
 15:10:48.775 21064-21468 MediaCodec                               I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder] setting surface generation to 21569538
 15:10:48.775 21064-21468 SurfaceUtils                             D  disconnecting from surface 0xb4000076f5ddfff0, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
 15:10:48.775 21064-21468 SurfaceUtils                             D  connecting to surface 0xb4000076f5ddfff0, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
 15:10:48.777 21064-21468 Codec2-Out...ufferQueue                  D  remote graphic buffer migration 17/17
 15:10:48.778 21064-21468 Codec2Client                             D  setOutputSurface -- failed to set consumer usage (6/BAD_INDEX)
 15:10:48.778 21064-21468 Codec2Client                             D  setOutputSurface -- generation=21569538 consumer usage=0x900
 15:10:48.783 21064-21468 Codec2Client                             D  Surface configure completed
 15:10:48.783 21064-21468 SurfaceUtils                             D  disconnecting from surface 0xb4000076f5db78c0, reason disconnectFromSurface
 15:10:48.791 21064-21064 (DefaultPl...achSurface                  D  Player: action detach
 15:10:48.792 21064-21064 (DefaultPl...achSurface                  D  Player: action detach successful
 15:10:49.407 21064-21064 Choreographer                            I  Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```